# Spring Data JPA Hibernate - LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a project in Spring Boot and Hibernate. Previous entities operated on Eclipselink, but were adapted to the JPA standard.
Every time I try to download a single object I get an exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.example.demo.model2.Color # 19] - no Session
```

As far as I know, this message appears with @OneToMany, @ManyToOne relations. But I created a new example project. And even for an entity without @OneToMany is the same problem. I do not know what's wrong. What could be the reason?

Entity Color:

```
package com.example.demo.model2;  
import lombok.Data;  
import javax.persistence.*;  
@Data  
@Entity  
@Table(name = "COLOR")  
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_color", sequenceName = "seq_color", allocationSize = 1)  
public class Color {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_color")
private Long id;
private String bluecolor = "";
private String redcolor = "";
private String greencolor = "";
private int index = 0; }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ColorRepository extends JpaRepository<Color, Long> {
}
```

SimplyService:

```
@Service
public class SimplyService{

    @Autowired
    ColorRepository colorRepository;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    void test(){
        Color color= colorRepository.getOne(19L);
        playlist.getBluecolor();
    }
}
```

DemoApplication:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo.repository")
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.example.demo.model2")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database
spring.datasource.username=base
spring.datasource.password=base
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Postgresql Color Table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.color
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    bluecolor character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    index integer,
    redcolor character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    greencolor character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT t_color_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.color
    OWNER to base;
```

Answer (score 0):

`getOne()` calls `EntityManager.getReference()`. It returns an uninitialized proxy, without even going to the database. That is useful when you want to attach entity that you know exists, to another entity you're creating or modifying.

To get data from the database, use `findById()`, not `getOne()`.